# Remove name from moderncv footer

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

The moderncv documentclass creates a footer on the résumé page without a name, yet adds it on the subsequent letter page. Is there a simple way to omit one's name in the footer altogether?

(It appears to me that it must be the `\makecvtitle` and `\makelettertitle` that trigger different footer styles)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{First name}{Last name}
\address{Address}{City}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\clearpage
\recipient{Company}{Address\\City}
\date{Date}
\opening{Dear ...,}
\makelettertitle

Letter

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the `\name` arguments are **only** used on the top of the resume and on the subsequent page footers, then one could do this, `\makeatletter\name{First name\gdef\@firstname{}}{Last name\gdef\@lastname{}}\makeatother` which zeroes out the quantities after their first use

Comment: I never used this documentclass but please give it a try to replace `\makelettertitle` by `\makeletterhead`. If this works, I will write an answer.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi it does. But what's the difference?

Comment: @BenjaminH `\makelettertitle` is defined as `\newcommand*{\makelettertitle}{ \makeletterhead\makeletterfoot}`. Similar thing for `\makecvtitle`. As the OP was happy with the cvfoot in the first place (first page), I just kicked it out for the following pages. I hope, this is clear. There is no big documentation on this class and I do not know it. Therefore Alexander should test if my approach is really stable.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks! So the rest of the footer is still printed because it was set by makecvtitle?

Comment: @BenjaminH That was my assumption. If I got the code of that package right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be side-effects, but you could just reset your name at the beginning of the letter by setting `\name{}{}` to empty strings:

```
\clearpage
\name{}{}
\recipient{Company}{Address\\City}
\date{Date}
\opening{Dear ...,}
```

It worked in your MWE, but maybe there are problems in bigger documents.

Comment: I amazingly didn't try that. I thought I had to use some `\renewcommand` stuff, but simply adding `\name{}{}` at the end of the letter page worked. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you'd rather use LaRiFaRi's solution in the comments of your question. It seems "more right".

Answer (score 2):

if you are happy to remove the footer completely you could just use `\makecvtitle` followed by `\pagestyle{empty}`.

If you want the footer on some pages but not others (for whatever reason) then you can insert it using `\thispagestyle{plain}` in the appropriate position.